# error: failed to push some refs to when trying to deploy nodejs app on bitbucket with codeship

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, bitbucket

Hello I am trying to deply a nodejs app with codeship. The repo is on bitbucket I've set everything up and when I make a change commit and push to deploy the app on heroku I get this error in codeship

```
To git@heroku.com:awesomeqanda.git
! [remote rejected] ea759f32a266f24be65e6eeef9fd5f654bb707b4 -> master (shallow update not allowed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:appname.git'
```

I've tried fetching and pulling everything is up to date I also tried a Force git push and same error. Please help

Comment: I've never had more than 1 remote. It's a project where 2 people work in a bitbucket repo. We've always pushed to origin master

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch with unshallow from your source repo with the following command before you attempt to push;

```
git fetch --unshallow master
```

(your source/upstream repo may not be called `master`, in which case you should substitute as appropriate.